# Delete file from a specific directory in Laravel local storage

Tags: php, laravel, file

I am storing files at local storage. So, in `/storage/app/public` directory.

I am storing my files in  `/storage/app/public/userId/images` ;

I used `php artisan storage:link` , so I can access that files in view, having a shortcut to this folder in  `/public/storage/userId/images` 
Inside that path I have 2 images -  `test.jpg` and `test2.jpg`

I can't find a response at Laravel documentation, how to delete  file `test.jpg` from `/public/storage/userId/images`

I tried in this way :

```
$path = 'public/' . $id . '/diploma';
$files =  Storage::files($path);
return $files;
```

It returns me :

```
[
"public/303030/images/test.jpg"
"public/303030/images/test2.jpg"
]
```

Now, how can I call  `Storage::delete('test.jpg')` on that array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is multiple ways to delete image

```
//In laravel 
File::delete($image);
//for specific directory
File::delete('images/' . 'image1.jpg');
```

and other way (Simple PHP)

```
//Simple PHP
unlink(public_path('storage/image/delete'));
```

and if you want to delete more than 1 images than

```
Storage::delete(['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg']);
//or
File::delete($image1, $image2, $image3);
```

for more detail about [Delete File in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem)

Comment: So, if `$image = 'test.jpg'`.  how `File::delete($image)` will know what image to delete, and from each folder? 
P.S. Please, review my edit

Comment: $path = '/public/' . $userId . '/images/test.jpg' ;
Storage::delete('$path);

Now it works. I tried in your way, but it works just after adding `/public` as well.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `Storage::disk('public')->delete('img_001.png');` this works

Answer (score 3):

Use [Storage::delete()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#deleting-files). The `delete` method accepts a single filename or an array of files to remove from the disk.

```
Storage::delete($file_to_delete);
```

May be you want to do something like-

```
$files =  Storage::files($path);
Storage::delete($files);
```

Comment: So, if $image = 'test.jpg'. how Storage::delete($image) will know what image to delete, and from each folder? P.S. Please, review my edit

Comment: you need to specify the filename with path

Comment: $path = '/public/' . $userId . '/images/test.jpg' ;
Storage::delete('$path);

Now it works. I tried in your way, but it works just after adding `/public` as well.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @priMo-ex3m glad it helps :), accept the one that helps you, that way it can be useful in future for others

Comment: Sure, just waiting for time out. I will accept first one, just cause it was answered earlier. But in fact, answers are equivalent. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
use File;


  public function destroy($id,$src)
    {

        File::delete('file/' . $src);
        fileModel::find($id)->delete();
        return back()->withErrors("");
    }
```

if you store your image `public/file` folder you can delete like this . it will work . in the **`$src`** just pass the file name .
Example:  $src = example.png;