# how to delete mp3 file from folder using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to delete the mp3 file from my local folder but unfortunately, it's not deleting please help me how to do that thanks?

**controller**

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {   

        $hamdnaat = HamdoNaat::findOrFail($request->deleteId);

        // apply your conditional check here
        if (false) {
            $response['error'] = 'This  hamdnaat has something assigned to it.';
            return response()->json($response, 409);
        } else {
            Storage::disk('audiofile')->delete($hamdnaat);
            $response = $hamdnaat->delete();
            // form helpers.php
            logAction($request);

            return response()->json($response, 200);
        }
    }
```

filesystem.php

```
  'audiofile' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('uploads/audio'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads/audio',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete file from a specific directory in Laravel local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317981/delete-file-from-a-specific-directory-in-laravel-local-storage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the file name to the delete function when you try deleting a file. So use

```
Storage::disk('audiofile')->delete($hamdnaat['name']);
```

If the name field doesn't include the extension, make sure you add it.

```
Storage::disk('audiofile')->delete($hamdnaat['name'] + '.mp3');
```

Comment: please can you explain to me what is name?

Comment: It's the file name. I'm assuming that you stored it. Of course, the key can be something else.